# UIToolbar translucent like photos app

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar, uiappearance

I was wondering how to make the UIToolbar look transparent like the photos app where it allows the photo below it to be seen.  I have my UIToolbar placed in IB.  In IB, I set both the tintColor and backgroundColor to ClearColor.

In code, I also do:

```
_webViewToolbar.translucent = YES;
_webViewToolbar.alpha = 0.5;
```

Unfortunately, it only looks like this:

[image]

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check the following line of code

```
 _toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;//Deprecated
```

**EDIT**

```
  _toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
  _toolbar.translucent = YES;
```

check the `UIInterface.h` Class in `UIKit.Framework`

You will find the follwing

```
// for UINavigationBar and UIToolBar

 typedef enum {
 UIBarStyleDefault          = 0,
 UIBarStyleBlack            = 1,

 UIBarStyleBlackOpaque      = 1, // Deprecated. Use UIBarStyleBlack
 UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent = 2, // Deprecated. Use UIBarStyleBlack and set the translucent property to YES
 } UIBarStyle;
```

Regards,
neil.